# How to make a responsive horizontal rule

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to adapt this hr so that it can appear on mobile on one line. This code is fine for a desktop view but for a mobile device it creates a jump to the line that breaks the hr.

```css
div {
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 30%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mcnTextContent">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="center">
    <hr>TOGETHER
    <hr>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if the "<hr>" tags were self-closed ("<hr />"), to make it obvious that there are supposed to be two tags and the second one isn't a typo for "</hr>".

Answer (score 1):

Your estimate of 20px for the width of TOGETHER was way out. 
Below I have used 8em but you may want to adjust that a little one way or the other.

```css
div { text-align: center; } 
hr { display: inline-block; width: calc((100% - 8em)/2); }
```

```html
<div class="mcnTextContent">
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
  <div style="center">
    <hr>TOGETHER
    <hr>
  </div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh ok ! I get it . Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Option One:
Use a single, full-width (or maybe something like 90%?) <HR> but move `TOGETHER` up so that it sits on top.

Option Two:
Use `calc` in your CSS so that the width of each <HR> is  (width of parent - width of TOGETHER) / 2

(Guessing at 30% width is just too fragile in this case).

Comment: Both of them will work if done right - post your code if you are still having issues.

Comment: This is the code I tried in CSS                                                                              div {
  text-align: center;
}

hr {
  display: inline-block;
   width: calc((100% - 20px)/2);
}